# Opposite of 'else' during a switch or conditional

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm wondering if any programming language has an operator like so (`ALWAYS` is a placeholder--I'm asking what language has something like `ALWAYS`)

```
if a
  doAStuff()
else if b
  doBStuff()
ALWAYS
  //runs if a or b is true
  win()
else
  doElse()
```

Basically, the opposite of `else`.  It runs if something else in the statement ran.

logically, it would be like this

```
always = true
if a
  doA()
else if b
  doB()
else
  always = false
  doElse()
if always
  win()
```

Does any language have that logic built into a keyword, such as `ALWAYS` from the first example?

Comment: That would defeat the point of having ALWAYS. Might as well use more if else loops.

Comment: switch with a goto label is probably the closest

Comment: I edited the question, I am wondering what language has something like `ALWAYS` from the first example.  Or are there languages that have implemented `ALWAYS` and even called it that?

Comment: If it only executes when the `else` block does not, then it isn't *always*. You could call it *notElse*. We do have ways of saying "always" -- for example, a statement following the selection statement. Or more strongly, in Java, the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

Not really 'language-agnostic'.  More like 'find-my-language'.  With Forth and Lisp you can *add* such a construct naturally to the language, and it will work just like existing constructs.  I'm not aware of any language that has it by default.  If you have a less extensible language than Forth or Lisp, then the natural ways to do this are to use a local function (if you have first-class functions) or to set a flag as you show, or else to factor the code such that both conditions can be treated as pairs without a lot of repetition.

So, in JavaScript:

```
;(function() {
  function both() { win(); more stuff, potentially }
  if (a) { doA(); if (b) both() }
  else if (b) { doB(); if (a) both() }
  else neither()
})()
```

At upon reading that, it should be clear that the 'both' case is never going to happen in that second block.  So this simplifies to:

```
;(function() {
  function both() { win(); more stuff, potentially }
  if (a) { doA(); if (b) both() }
  else if (b) doB()
  else neither()
})()
```

Which doesn't seem worth the effort.  So it seems even less worth a language feature.  Why not go further and write this?

```
if (a) { doA(); if (b) { win(); more stuff, potentially } }
else if (b) doB()
else neither()
```

If `b` is an expensive test, just save the result of it.  If `b` must not be tested before `a`, save both results.  Obviously, both tests must always be run anyway.

```
;(function() {
  var a = testA(),
      b = testB()
  ... as above ...
})()
```

As for the last option, "factor the code such that both conditions can be treated as pairs", what you're looking for is:

```
if (a && !b) doA()
if (!a && b) doB()
if (a && b) { doA(); doB(); win() }  // or no doB() if you really want that
if (!a && !b) neither()
```

With `else if` if you like.  I'd prefer this option actually in a pattern-matching language.  Mercury will even throw an compile-time error if you forget one of the four possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but a simple do-while loop will ALWAYS run at least once in Java.